# How to add watermark on existing Word Document using PHPWord?

Tags: php, doc, phpword

I'm trying to add a watermark on my existing Word document but am unable to add it. There are a lot of examples of creating new docs & then editing them according to your need. But I could not find any tutorial to edit a pre-existing Word document.

Below is my Code:

```
<?php
require_once '../PHPWord.php';

// New Word Document
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// New portrait section
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// Create header
$header = $section->createHeader();

// Add a watermark to the header
$header->addWatermark('_earth.jpg', array('marginTop'=>200, 'marginLeft'=>55));

$section->addText("Hello World");

// Save File
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('Watermark.docx');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example here:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_11_ReadWord2007.php

Particular to your question, to open the document, you need to replace the line

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
```

with

```
$PHPWord = PhpWord\IOFactory::load('<file path of your MSWord document>'); // or \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory depending on your environment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHPOffice spreadspheet library

Sampl eworkingcode is below

```
<?php 

require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

// Your word file as input / existing file
$name = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
$name="sample";
$source = __DIR__ . "/{$name}.docx";

$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);


// Get the initial Section of header and add watermark image to it
$section = $phpWord->getSection(0);
$header = $section->createHeader();
$header->addWatermark('watermark_sample.png', array('marginTop' => 0, 'marginLeft' => 0));


// write the output file
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
```